# onerror to terminate request

Tags: javascript, extjs, onerror

I use the below onerror function for non-EXT errors. My Extjs page is still showing 'Loading' even after the flow goes to the onerror function and it returns false. Please let me know how to stop the request, and go the previous user entry text box from onerror.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
        alert('Server error caught in window.onerror');
            return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: does the message 'Server error caught in window.onerror' alerts correctly ?

Comment: Yes, exactly when the error occurs.

Comment: are you processing an ajax request ?

Comment: Yes, Ajax request is processed.

Comment: as far as I know, no error event is fired, when using `window.onerror`. It is a way to gather in-depth informations of the nature of the error (without having to use your console)

Comment: btw the way, if you use `$.ajax` jquery method, you won't have those kind of problems. The syntax looks like `$.ajax('url', {
success: function(response) {
somemethod();
},
error: function(request, errorType, errorMessage) {
alert('Error: ' + errorType + ' with message: ' + errorMessage);
}
 }); `

Comment: or hide the loading mask

Comment: @DarinKolev how do I hide the loading mask?

Comment: Which Version of extjs are u using?

Comment: 4.1.1 version... Feel like using try-catch to handle the errors